# Average count of "numbers bigger than it's predecessors" on a random ordering of $ \left[ 1 ... n \right] $

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Note: Please refer me to other references of this problem in literature or web if you can. I did not find it in web myself, I don't know what keywords to use. I "invented" this problem myself.

Problem: We have randomly ordered the numbers from 1 to N. A element of this list is called "record" (word i coined based on [world record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_record)) if it's bigger than the numbers before him on the list. Let's define the first number of the list as a record, so as to agree, this is not a important decision that affects the mechanics of the problem at all.

Then, if we pick a random sequence, what is the expected value of the number of records?

Example: The sequence 12354 has 4 records: 1,2,3,5, 4 is not because 5>4 and it's before 4.

Answer (score 3):

Define $A(n)$ as the average of records in a random sequence of $[1,N]$. Then, we know $A(1)=1$. Also, on a random ordering of $[n+1]$, there is probability  $1/(n+1)$ that the biggest number $(n+1)$ it's the last one. If it isn't, you can throw it away and you get a random sequence ordering of $n$ numbers consisting of the $[n+1]$ list minus some number $x$, but this is analogous (in the sense of having the same number of records) to a random ordering of $[1,N]$, which we, inductively, assume to know it's expected value.

Then we know the recurrence relation $A(n+1)=A(n)+1/(n+1)$
Because we know the initial value $A(1)=1$, we have:

In conclusion: $$ A(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \approx \ln(n)$$

Answer (score 2):

These are called left-to-right maxima, and it's a classic result that the expected number of them in a permutation of $\{1,2,\cdots, n\}$ is $H_n$. You can see this by letting $X_i$ be the indicator random variable for $i$ being a left-to-right maxima, and then using linearity of expectation.

Comment: Great! What is $H_n$?

Comment: The $n^{\text{th}}$ harmonic number.

Comment: @Santropedro The [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) $H_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n\frac1i$.